# NodeJS and Dygraphs

Tags: jquery, node.js, postgresql, dygraphs

I try to draw a (Dy)graph ... currently running NodeJs - a little bit of HTML.

My question is: My data is stored in a postgreSQL DB...How do i load the data from my datasource and into my NODEJS FILE? All example by DyGraphs...is inline or loading from a text file...i have million of data point - so the solution should have performance like no. 1 criteria...

If you would approach this in a very different way - another way to construct and build this code - please tell me! My only demand is it runs NodeJS...

### HTML FILE

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/dygraphs/dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="demodiv"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
        <script>
            draw_chart();
        </script>
    </body> </html>
```

### NODEJS FILE:

```
function draw_chart() {

    new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("demodiv"),
        "chart.csv"
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I never use the database. DyGraphs already suppport .cvs files out-of-the box. So instead i make my calculations server side, and at the client i make a request for the .csv file directly from within the dygraph object...local path or URL - DyGraphs is happy with both :-)